how to fade out the texture on the edges of the model?
I am making a model of the PS5 controller and I am facing a problem with the texturing part, i have downloaded a texture for the back part of the controller, I want the texture to look like the texture in the reference image but after applying that texture I don't know how to fade out the texture on the edges like in the reference image(blue lines for edges).
You can see the current material in the shader tab to see the material nodes and 3rd images for its result on my model. Can anyone please help me?




A Normal image texture should be used with a Normal Map node. If you want to combine it with a Bump node then connect it to the Normal slot.

Create a b&w image that you'll use as a mask between your pattern and a pure white:


With the Bump node, pure white means "fully raised". Shouldn't the mid level then be a gray value like #808080 (without the gamma correction that Blender adds) to have it "flat"? Otherwise the pattern will look like it has been engraved.

Sure it depends on if its patterns are bumps or hollows

ok, thanks I'll try that
